# C# wcf service plugin model

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, plugins

I am planning a project which will be a management system for my companies proprietary server technology.  The system will consist of three main components: a service that runs on the servers we want to control, a central management server that sends commands/gets data from the services, and client application that connects to the central management server.  These components will be written in C#, and communicate via WCF.

The challenge I face is enabling plugin-in support for the service running on the servers.  Most of the tutorials/examples I've found are 10 years old, and none deal with the implications of WCF.

Here is an example of the functionality I need:

Another developer at my company (who doesn't have access to the source of the system) wants to be able to get the disk space for the C:\ drive on one of the servers using the client app of the management system.  He will create a dll which is copied to the server, and added to the config file for the service.  He should now be able to get the disk space for that server with no further changes to the system.

A nice-to-have, although I'm not sure this is possible, would be to support plugins written in either C#, C++, or Delphi.

I am looking for a place to start, some tutorials/examples, and a general concept of how the system (and WCF service contracts) should handle the plugins.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

There are no real implications of WCF on the effect of a plugin, you just add the config information for the new WCF endpoint in you `app.config` or `web.config` file of the hosting app and you are done.

You should be able to use any tutorial on writing plugins in C# and should be fine. [This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6334/Plug-ins-in-C) covers it pretty well, the only change I would do is instead of scanning the folder for dll's you have a list in the config file explicitly listing each plugin you want loaded.

Also you may want to load the plugins in separate `AppDomain`s so if one plugin goes down it does not necessarily bring down the entire program.

For loading Unmanaged plugins in C++ or Delphi you will likely need the developer to write a small managed wrapper that will take care of calling the unmanaged code and cleaning up after itself.